# How do I limit the values allowed in a generic const parameter?

Tags: rust

I have struct with a generic constant:

```rust
pub struct Data<const N: usize>;

impl<const N: usize> Data<N> {
   
    pub fn new() -> Self()  {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

I can then instantiate a `Data<N>` instance with:

```rust
d = Data::<64>::new();
```

this works fine - however I would like to limit the valid values of `N` to a handful of different valid values. I can of course implement this with a runtime check in `Data::<N>::new()` - but if possible I would prefer to do it compile time. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way, if you only have few values, is to create a trait and implement it only for `Data<VALID_VALUES>`:

```rust
pub trait ValidValue {}

impl ValidValue for Data<8> {}
impl ValidValue for Data<64> {}

impl<const N: usize> Data<N> {
    pub fn new() -> Self
    where
        Self: ValidValue,
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you have many values, and it is hard to count them all, you can use a compile-time assert. Beware: this causes a *post-monomorphization* error, meaning it won't show up in `cargo check` - only `cargo build`.

On nightly:

```rust
#![feature(inline_const)]

impl<const N: usize> Data<N> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        const { assert!(N <= 100, "invalid value") };
        
        // ...
    }
}
```

On stable, you can use an associated constant to emulate `inline_const`:

```rust
impl<const N: usize> Data<N> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        struct Assert<const N: usize>;
        impl<const N: usize> Assert<N> {
            const ASSERT: () = assert!(N <= 100, "invalid value");
        }
        _ = Assert::<N>::ASSERT;
        
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternative one works great for me - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use generic const expressions, but currently, is possible only on nightly, but be aware that is incomplete feature, what can cause compiler to crash.

So, how to use it? Most easiest way just to add const_guards crate and use it. It would look like this:

```
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]
use const_guards::guard;

#[guard(N <= 64)]
pub struct Data<const N: usize>;
```

But if you don't want to use external crates, simplest code with generic const exprs would look like this.

```
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

pub struct Data<const N: usize>
where
    Guard<{ N <= 64 }>: Protect;

pub struct Guard<const U: bool>;
pub trait Protect {}
impl Protect for Guard<true> {}
```